# global scope varies based on datatype

Tags: python

I have two global variables, one int and another list.
I am able to modify the list within one of the function definitions, but not the int(without using the global statement).

```py
i = 2000
lst = range(0,3)

def AddM():   
  i=i+1 
  lst.append(10)
```

What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: [Why am I getting an `UnboundLocalError` when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Comment: Search StackOverflow for questions about this.  Hint: `=` is not the same as `append`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is much simpler, than you might expect.

1. In your AddM() function, you actually created a "new" variable called "i" within the local namespace of your function, which is the default namespace for any new asignments made within a function.
2. That local "i" has been assigned the value of the "global" i (which you defined previously outside the function in the global namespace), plus one.
3. Then you exited you function and "nothing happend" to the global "i".
   I would assume you that is what you were wondering here.

You need to learn how to use the global statement here.
Please refer to the documentation and read carefully:

globals() is a dictionary containing all global variables:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals

Usage of the "global" keyword in Python:
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement

A random example I found via google on how to fix your program:
stereochro.me/ideas/global-in-python

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

As python doc clearly mentioned

```
This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope.
```

define scope of that variable as global.

```
>>> i = 2000
>>> def AddM():
...     global i
...     x += 1
>>> p = AddM()
>>>print p
2001
```

global simply influences scope and name resolution. Here with list you are just modifying already existed list and appending new element that's why you do not need to define it as global.